# MVC5 JSON parsing

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have this JSON from a 3rd party system (so I can't change the JSON). I am trying to get it to parse into a list of MethodItems, but my `Items` collection is always `null`. I am using the built-in MVC 5 JSON deserializer in a controller action. What am I missing.

```
{ "Method": {
        "name": "GetItems",
        "items": {
            "Item 1": {
                "name": "myItem",
                "value": "toothbrush"
            },
            "Item 2": {
                "name": "my item 2",
                "value": "razor"
            }
        }
 }
```

C# objects here

```
public class RequestRoot {
    public Method Method { get; set; }
}

public class Method {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MethodItem[] Items { get; set; }
}

public class MethodItem {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `items` is not an array. It is two objects with the same property names.

Comment: it is a variable length tho. I can have many of those repeated. Is there anything I can do to get it to map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Items` should be treat as a dictionary, try something like this:

```
public class Method 
{

    public string name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,MethodItem> items { get; set; }

}

public class MethodItem 
{

    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }

}
```